# How to get date from 2020-02-27T15:00:43+0000 format

Tags: android, formatdatetime

Hello what I am trying to do is compare a `date` I have in specific format(2020-02-27T15:00:43+0000 format) and today's date.

Just the date not the time.

```
String saleDate=2020-02-27T15:00:43+0000;

            public static int validateCustomer(int idCustomer, double saleBalance, double totalSaleValue, String saleDate){
    Config config= new Config().getConfig();
    ModuleRoute moduleRoute = new ModuleRoute().getModulesRoute(config.idRoute);
    double limit = (double) moduleRoute.allowPercentage;
    double paid =totalSaleValue-saleBalance;
    Date saleDateFormatD = null;
    Date dateToday = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat saleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
    try {
        saleDateFormatD = saleDateFormat.parse(saleDate);
    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    SimpleDateFormat justDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String formatSaleDateTime = justDateFormat.format(saleDateFormatD);
    String todayDate= justDateFormat.format(dateToday);
    if (formatSaleDateTime.equals(todayDate)){
        return 0;
    }else if ((paid)>(limit)*totalSaleValue){
        return 1;
    }else
        return 2;
    //if customer can, return true


}
```

In this case, it will be check if `dt` and `date1` are the same.

`date` is a string in that format.
Any help or suggestions would be great. thanks

Comment: where `dt` & `date`?

Comment: date is a string that has that form. dt is the Date format of "date". I need to do if(dt==date1) something like this

Comment: i asked, where have you declared both in your code?

Comment: I edited the code, maybe you could have a better look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, hope it may help you

```
    //Declare it in your class.   
private static final DateFormat  sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");      //Changed here
    //just set your saleDate as
String saleDate = "2020-02-27"; //now both are in same format

Date newDate = new Date();
String newDateFormat = sdf.format(newDate);
Log.d(TAG, "New Date: " + newDateFormat ); // It gave me output as - D/TAG: New Date: 2020-02-28
if (newDateFormat.equalsIgnoreCase(saleDate))  // make your static date as of same format ("yyyy-MM-dd")
{
      //Date is matched
}
```

You will get your current time in the format you specified.

Now you can compare both strings(newDateFormat & date) easily.(Both are in same format).

Perform just simple string equals on both strings.

Comment: thanks for the reply. But how can I compare just the date withouth the time. I need to check day, month and year

Comment: Check my updated answer ... if thats not what you want then can you give me output of both strings like how do you want it? like in which format?

Comment: @AlejandroVargas if it helped you, you can upvote it.

Comment: done. Could you check this out, maybe could help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60455435/how-to-avoid-the-application-from-doing-too-much-work-on-its-main-thread

Answer (score 0):

Here I have a generic function that works for almost everthing (keeping the Daylight saving time):

```js
function calcDiff2Dates(llegada, salida) {
    //DESMENUZAMOS ESE STRING
    var salidaParts = salida.split("/");
    var llegadaParts = llegada.split("/");

    // los meses empiezan en 0, de ahí -> dataParts[1] - 1
    var salidaDateObject = new Date(+salidaParts[2], salidaParts[1] - 1, +salidaParts[0]);
    var llegadaDateObject = new Date(+llegadaParts[2], llegadaParts[1] - 1, +llegadaParts[0]);

    //RECOGEMOS EL VALOR DE UN DIA PARA OPERAR
    const oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
    const diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((llegadaDateObject - salidaDateObject) / oneDay));

    //PASAMOS VALOR DEL CAMPO:
    //guardamos en var el htlm field que queremos popular
    var diasFiltroTop = $('#totalDiasFiltroTop');
    diasFiltroTop.html(diffDays);
};
```

Pass as a variable and should be ready:

```js
var salida = document.getElementById('fechaArrivalFiltroTop').innerHTML;
var llegada = document.getElementById('fechaDepartureFiltroTop').innerHTML;

    calcDiff2Dates(llegada, salida);
```

**In your case if its return 0 then its the same day.**